# Within jetpack compose how would you recommend going about making an image zoomable

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

Ideally what I would like to do is dump the image into a painter to make full screen within the `clickable` modifier, but I don't see a way to do that.

I see I can get the painter from `onSuccess`, but still not sure how to make all the pieces come together.

```
            LazyColumn(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
            ) {
                itemsIndexed(photoAlbum) { _, photo ->
                    AsyncImage(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .height(300.dp)
                            .padding()
                            .clickable {
                                // here is where I would think I'd get the painter image?
                            },
                        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                        model = Constants().supaBasePhotoURL + photo + ".jpg",
                        placeholder = painterResource(id = R.drawable.smokehill),
                        contentDescription = "image of hots post",
                        onSuccess = {
                            painter.value = it.painter
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
```

Comment: There are several existing implementations of this, such as [this one](https://saket.github.io/telephoto/) and [this one](https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Compose-Zoom). See also [this Medium post](https://proandroiddev.com/zoomable-image-with-jetpack-compose-13b050675da5).

Comment: Thank you! I was not aware of some of these and the zoomable package was exactly what I needed.